# errorMessage: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action},

Tags: android, android-facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

i am developing an android app to post a status to user news feed.it works fine with my Facebook developer account. when i uses other(fb) account it show the error message given above. my code is here

```
currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();//this line is in onCreate Method
```

after press post button the method open is=>

```
// Method For Link Sharing
public void updateView(final String msg) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Session.openActiveSession(PostStatus.this, true,
            new Session.StatusCallback() {
                @Override
                public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                        Exception exception) {

                    /**
                     * share the  link on facebook
                     */

                    if (session.isOpened()) {
                        Session.openActiveSessionWithPermissionPublish(
                                PostStatus.this, true,
                                new Session.StatusCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void call(Session session,
                                            SessionState state,
                                            Exception exception) {
                                        // /**
                                        /**
                                         * share the video link on facebook
                                         */

                                        if (session.isOpened()) {

                                            Toast.makeText(
                                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                                    "Status uploading in progress please wait",
                                                    1000).show();

                                            Bundle parameters = new Bundle(
                                                    1);
                                            /*
                                             * parameters.putParcelable(
                                             * "picture", bitmap);
                                             */
                                            parameters.putString("message",
                                                    msg);

                                            parameters.putString(
                                                    "description",
                                                    "Via OneTouchKeys");
                                            Request request = new Request(
                                                    Session.getActiveSession(),
                                                    "me/feed", parameters,
                                                    HttpMethod.POST,
                                                    new Request.Callback() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onCompleted(
                                                                Response response) {
                                                            showPublishResult(
                                                                    "!!!!",
                                                                    response.getGraphObject(),
                                                                    response.getError());
                                                        }
                                                    });

                                            request.executeAsync();

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                /**
                                 * permission to publish on facebook
                                 */
                                , Arrays.asList(MY_PERMISSIONS_PUBLISH));

                    }

                }
            }
    /**
     * permission to publish on facebook
     */
    );

}
```

and

```
    // Permissions for access facebook sharing
public static final String[] MY_PERMISSIONS_PUBLISH = {"publish_actions" };
public static final String[] MY_PERMISSIONS_READ = { "basic_info" };
```

i export the app from eclipse with release key and save it into my developer account. i Don't know whether i don't take permission in a proper way or missing some step to use it for everyone.though it works only for my developer account.

Comment: check for the App Restrictions in the developer page

Comment: Have you solved this ?